# Django distinct foreign keys for use in another model

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, distinct

```
class Log:
  project = ForeignKey(Project)
  msg = CharField(...)
  date = DateField(...)
```

I want to select the four most recent Log entries where each Log entry must have a unique project foreign key. I've tried the solutions on google search but none of them works and the django documentation isn't that very good for lookup..

I tried:

```
id_list = Log.objects.order_by('-date').values_list('project_id').distinct()[:4]
entries = Log.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)
```

`id_list` is empty unless I remove the order_by() but then it's not in the correct order.

```
entries = Log.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)
```

The objects in entries is not in the same order as in `id_list` because when you use Mysql function IN() it will not sort the result by the input order ... How to do it in django?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is impossible to achieve what you want with django orm. Documentation states that is not possible to use order_by along with distinct.

However there might be another way to solve it. Maybe you could select Project objects, and annotate them with latest log entries.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Skirmantas is right and you have to do it in a more complex way:

```
from django.db.models import Max
projects = Project.objects.annotate(last_logged=Max('log__date')).order_by('-last_logged')[:4]
log_entries = [proj.log_set.order_by('-date')[0] for proj in projects]
```

Comment: I get: NameError at /

global name 'Max' is not defined ?

Comment: Try: `from django.db.models import Max`

Comment: Thank you, but now it says "list index out of range" @ "log_entries = [proj.log_set.order_by('-date')[0] for proj in projects] "

Comment: @mrmclovin: ...which means that `log_set` for given `project` is empty, you have to deal with that case yourself because it's project-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single-query solution (but it will probably be too slow):

`Log.objects.filter(project__log__date__gte=F('date')).annotate(c=Count('project__log')).filter(c__lte=4).order_by('project', 'c')`

Comment: Thank you, I'm close to an solution that works. However, how do I user this together with {% regroup %} template tag? It seems that the ordering is not by date-field but project-field.

Comment: How and why do you want to regroup the result?

Comment: Look, I want to select the 3 most recent logs for up to 3 different projects. When I present them in my template I want to put the log objects under each project ordered by the project who has got the most recent log first. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I still need help with this :)